# How to assign variables in a recursion?

Tags: prolog

Suppose you have a bunch of boxes inside other boxes, i.e.

```
inBox(a,b).
inBox(b,c).
inBox(c,d).
```

inBox(x,y) meansbox x is in box y. Now I want to write a method to determine if one box is inside of another box, e.g. insideBox(a,d) = true since a is inside b, which is inside c, which is inside d. So it appears to be a naturally recursive problem and my attempt at solving it fails to initialize my variable to "move one box up":

```
insideBox(X, Y) :- inBox(X, Y), inBox(X, Z), insideBox(Z,Y).
```

The logic is to first check the base case of whether or not box X is currently inside box Y, if not then call inBox(X, Z) to get a value for which box X is in and then recall the recursive method. I have tried looking at the trace but can't reason what is going on:

```
| ?- insideBox(a,d).
  1    1  Call: insideBox(a,d) ? c
  2    2  Call: inBox(a,d) ? c
  2    2  Fail: inBox(a,d) ? c
  1    1  Fail: insideBox(a,d) ? c
```

I've tried other stuff like Z is inBox(X, _) for setting the variable Z but this hasn't worked either and I have no clue how Z is ending up with the value of a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
?- insideBox(a,d).

inBox(a,b).
inBox(b,c).
inBox(c,d).

insideBox(X,Z) :- inBox(X,Z).
insideBox(X,Z) :- inBox(X,Y), insideBox(Y,Z).
```

Just a side-note: be careful with the terms you use. You don't "assign" variables, instead you "unify" them. Also you're not writing "methods", you're writing "predicates".

Comment: I will try to keep the terminology in mind, I was quite terrible at proper terminology when learning physics as well. Also is there any way to make it so that it only returns true instead of returning true and then searching for more solutions eventually leading to false?

Comment: @Greg - Usually prolog only succeeds once, unless you ask it to try to find more solutions. There must be a setting in the system you use. Again, though, prolog doesn't "return" anything. It either succeeds or it fails.